# CLGeocoder only returns first look up result

Tags: ios, mkmapview, clgeocoder

I'm experiencing a weird issue with `- (void)geocodeAddressString:(NSString *)addressString completionHandler:(CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)completionHandler;`.

I have a list of locations need to be looked up. So I did something like

```
for (Trip *trip in takenTrips) {
    [geoCoder geocodeAddressString:trip.location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        //handling result
    }];
}
```

But it seems the completion handler is only being called once. I tried making these lookups sequentially. Then everything works fine.

I searched around for a while, but couldn't find anything similar to this. I'm totally baffled here...

Any suggestion is welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications should be conscious of how they use geocoding. rules of thumb for using this class effectively: Send at most one geocoding request for any one user action. [class link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html)

To solve your problem you could the one of the following:

1. Do-while loop that checks if geocoder is processing geocoding
2. NSOperationQueue to excucute one at time if it complete
3. in the completeHandle execute a callback that run the next geocode

Comment: Oh, I'm not aware of that. I'll do it sequentially then.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use more **geocoder**?

```
dispatch_queue_t geocoderQueue = dispatch_queue_create("geocoder.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT); 
dispatch_apply([takenTrips count], dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ull), ^(size_t index) {

    NSString *loc = [(Trip *)takenTrips[index] location];

    CLGeocoder *geoCoder = [CLGeocoder new];
    [geoCoder geocodeAddressString:loc completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks firstObject];
        NSLog(@"%@",placemark.postalCode);
    }];
});
```

and also in a **private concurrent queue** so you can have a great result in performance.